# Need help removing [ie] tag from migrated questions

Tags: support, migration, retag-request

I have just gone through and removed the [ie](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ie) tag from a few posts replacing it with [internet-explorer](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer). Since there were only 11, I did them manually.

Now I'm stuck because the following 2 questions have been migrated and I can't edit them to kill the tag. Can a moderator help me out please.

- [jQuery dialog open causes page to continuously lengthen in IE [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/246964/jquery-dialog-open-causes-page-to-continuously-lengthen-in-ie?noredirect=1)
- [IE9 setup needs to update java/firefox/chrome? [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/248747/ie9-setup-needs-to-update-java-firefox-chrome?noredirect=1)

Comment: FWIW, there are 74 tagged [ie8].

Comment: Yeah, I didn't plan on doing that manually :P I was going to suggest a synonym for that one.

Answer (score 3):

Done.

Feel free to propose your IE8 synonym as well. I keep an eye on the synonym list every few days, so when I see it I'll do a back-end merge.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried the synonym when I posted this but I don't have the required rep :( maybe someone else can propose it.

Comment: @BenPilbrow The rep-rules for synonyms are weird. It's an SO-holdover that doesn't hold up well on lower-rep sites.